# TurboVnc Server in Docker container, and VirtualGL in other?

Tags: docker

I have this scheme for a remote connection to docker app.

```
ContainerA Ip: 172.17.0.2

ContainerB Ip: 172.17.0.3
```

`vncserver` in the `containerA` run on port 5901 and exposed to others.

**containerA**[*vncserver*] <-- **containerB**[virtualGL + App]

ContainerB has `ENTRYPOINT ["/opt/VirtualGL/vglrun"]`

Then, I run: `docker exec containerB -d 172.17.0.2:5901 App`

But it fails with:

> fail to open Display 172.17.0.2:5901

How do I to communicate `virtualGL` with `vncserver`?

Comment: When you say the command fails, what is the error?

Comment: fail to open Display 172.17.0.2:5901